# Cloud Functions for Firebase onWrite trigger: snapshot.val is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created few functions in the same index.js file, which is `sendEmail`, `sendEmailByDbStatusChange` and `sendEmailConfirmation`.

`sendEmail`- To be call via HTTP/API

`sendEmailByDbStatusChange` - listening to DB while value change, but the action is hardcoded

`sendEmailConfirmation`- Listing to DB while value change, the action subject to the snapshot.

Below is my codes:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

// Sends an email confirmation when a user changes his mailing list subscription.
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.body.subject === undefined || req.body.recipient === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
    //res.status(400).send('subject/body/recipient is missing!');
    return false
  } else {
    const mailSubject = req.body.subject;
    const mailHtmlBody = req.body.htmlBody;
    const mailRecipient = req.body.recipient;



    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"Food Ninja." <foodninjaapp@gmail.com>',
      to: mailRecipient,
      subject: mailSubject,
      html: mailHtmlBody
    };

    //res.status(200).send('Success: ' + mailSubject + ' to ' + mailRecipient);

    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`${mailSubject}subscription confirmation email sent to: `, mailRecipient)
        return res.status(200).send('Success: ' + mailSubject + ' to ' + mailRecipient)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
  }
});

exports.sendEmailByDbStatusChange = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite((event) => {
  //const snapshot = event.data;
  //const val = snapshot.val();

  //if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {
  //  return null;
  //}

  const mailSubject = 'Sending email with Cloud Function - by DB onWrite Trigger';
  const mailHtmlBody = '<h1>Hello Jerry</h1><p>If you receiving this means that you have successfully deployed a customized firebase function</p><p>Be Happy!<br><br>Food Ninja Team</p>';
  const mailRecipient = 'admin@phd.com.my';

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Food Ninja." <foodninjaapp@gmail.com>',
    to: mailRecipient,
    subject: mailSubject,
    html: mailHtmlBody
  };

  //const subscribed = val.subscribedToMailingList;

  // Building Email message.
  //mailOptions.subject = subscribed ? 'Thanks and Welcome!' : 'Sad to see you go :`(';
  //mailOptions.text = subscribed ? 'Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.' : 'I hereby confirm that I will stop sending you the newsletter.';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() =>
      console.log(`${mailSubject}subscription confirmation email sent to: `, mailRecipient)
      //return res.status(200).send('Success: ' + mailSubject + ' to ' + mailRecipient)
    )
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
});

exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite((event2) => {
  console.log(event2)
  console.log(event2.val())
  console.log(event2.val().data)
  console.log(event2.data)
  console.log(event2.data.val())
  const snapshot = event2.data;
  console.log(snapshot)
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val)

  if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {
    return null;
  }

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Spammy Corp." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };

  const subscribed = val.subscribedToMailingList;

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = subscribed ? 'Thanks and Welcome!' : 'Sad to see you go :`(';
  mailOptions.text = subscribed ? 'Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.' : 'I hereby confirm that I will stop sending you the newsletter.';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log(`New ${subscribed ? '' : 'un'}subscription confirmation email sent to:`, val.email))
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
});
```

My problem is, after i deploy the code to firebase function, the console shows that the `sendEmailConfirmation` unable to execute smoothly due to `event2.val` is not a function.

My current code combined with my customize code and the original code, which `sendEmailConfirmation` is the original code. When run the original code independently it did work (original was `event` instead of `event2` for the snapshot).

Please advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you updated to v1.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, but didn't upgrade your code to match.

The entire process is explained in [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff). Right now you're being hit by the [changes in database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database), which shows that:

> #### Event data now a DataSnapshot
>
> In earlier releases, `event.data` was a `DeltaSnapshot`; now in v 1.0 it is a `DataSnapshot`.
>
> For `onWrite` and `onUpdate` events, the `data` parameter has `before` and `after` fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot` with the same methods available in `admin.database.DataSnapshot`. For example:
>
> **Before (<= v0.9.1)**
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((event) => {
>   const beforeData = event.data.previous.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = event.data.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```
>
> **Now (v1.0.0)**
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
>   const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```

According to that example, you'll need something along these lines:

```
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val)

  if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {
    return null;
  }

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Spammy Corp." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };

  const subscribed = val.subscribedToMailingList;

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = subscribed ? 'Thanks and Welcome!' : 'Sad to see you go :`(';
  mailOptions.text = subscribed ? 'Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.' : 'I hereby confirm that I will stop sending you the newsletter.';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log(`New ${subscribed ? '' : 'un'}subscription confirmation email sent to:`, val.email))
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
});
```

Comment: I don't get it ...   if it's a change object ...  then the if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList'))   test should not be valid anymore ...

Comment: How do I get the Parameter on the request the {uid} ?? Seems to have changed in the new version. Having that will complete the answer. Tks!

Before I was doing: req.params.uid but that won't work anymore.

Comment: Nothing changes on this since I wrote this answer. But my answer doesn't use params. It should be `context.params.uid`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context. If that doesn't work for you, open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Are you aware that there seems to be an error in the official Cloud functions sample code for sending an email, that you refer to in your answer (i.e. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/email-confirmation/functions/index.js). The following line seems to use a `changed()` method that does not exists: `if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {}`. Another SO member is encountering the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568219/nodemailer-error-while-using-gmail-in-firebase-functions

Comment: The `Snapshot.changed()` method was removed in 1.0. I wasn't aware of the outdated code in that sample. Please file a bug (and maybe even a PR) on the repo, since that's where it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.0.0 of the firebase-functions module, database [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) events now deliver a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object rather than a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) object as the first parameter.  You can read about all the breaking changes in 1.0.0 in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).  You should use this change object instead to choose if you want to examine the contents of the database before or after the change that invoked it.

Comment: if it's a change object ...  then the if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList'))   test is still not valid ...  right ?

Comment: No, click through to the API docs I linked for each method and object to understand how they work.  A Change object only has `before` and `after` properties.

Comment: thanks .. that's what I understand from your answer ...  so snapshot.changed() is NOT valid .. I don't understand how Jerry's code could work...  and it's still the current code in official examples updated to 1.0.0...  As you wrote the only way to check for a change is to compare both objects ( before and after )